# Adding two graph posts with same name in same page, the first one is taking also the result of the second

Tags: javascript, html, json, morris.js

### When i add a second graph in same page it happens this that is describes in photos below all the javascript code is here

```
  <div class="inbox-widget scrollbar-track-widgets scrollbar-track-gray nicescroll total_inspections-scrollbar">
<div id="total_inspections_comparison_content_chart"></div>
```

end of div

---

> Lines with javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = <?php echo json_encode($chart_data);?>;
var data_colors = <?php echo json_encode($data_colors);?>;
var data_labels = <?php echo json_encode($data_labels);?>;
var widget_parms = <?php echo json_encode($widget_parms);?>;

function createBarChart(element, data, xkey, ykeys, labels, lineColors, hoverCallBack)
{
    hoverCallBack = (typeof hoverCallBack == 'undefined') ? function (index, options, content, row)
    {
        return content;
    } : hoverCallBack;
    Morris.Bar({
        element: element,
        data: data,
        xkey: xkey,
        ykeys: ykeys,
        labels: labels,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true, //defaulted to true
        xLabelFormat: function (x) {
            return x.src.period;
        },
        gridLineColor: '#eeeeee',
        barSizeRatio: 1.3,
        barColors: lineColors,
        hoverCallback: hoverCallBack,
        preUnits: "",
        barSize: 10
    });
}

createBarChart(
    'total_inspections_comparison_content_chart',
    data,
    'date',
    ['three_years_back', 'two_years_back', 'last_year', 'this_year'],
    data_labels,
    function (row, series, type) {
        var now = new Date();
        var now_year = now.getFullYear();
        if(row.label.indexOf(now_year) >= 0 || (row.label === `Dec 31, ${now_year-1}` && (widget_parms == 'this_month' ||  widget_parms == 'year_to_date' || widget_parms == 'last_three_months')))
            color = data_colors[differenceYear(series.label)];
        else if (typeof data_colors[differenceYear(series.label - 1)]  != 'undefined') color = data_colors[differenceYear(series.label - 1)];
        else color = data_colors[differenceYear(series.label)];
        return color;
    },
    function (index, options, content, row)
    {
        $tooltip_info_obj = generateTooltip(options, content, row);
        return $tooltip_info_obj;
    }
);

function generateTooltip(options, content, row){
    var $jQueryObject = $($.parseHTML('<div>' + content + '</div>'));
    $jQueryObject.find('.morris-hover-row-label').addClass('hover-label-style');
    var tooltipInfo = '';
    tooltipInfo = '<strong>' + row.period + '</strong><br>';

    if(row.three_years_back !== 0){
        tooltipInfo += row.three_years_back_label + ': ' + row.three_years_back + '<br>';
    }
    if(row.two_years_back !== 0){
        tooltipInfo += row.two_years_back_label + ': ' + row.two_years_back + '<br>';
    }
    if(row.last_year !== 0){
        tooltipInfo += row.last_year_label + ': ' + row.last_year + '<br>';
    }
    if(row.this_year !== 0){
        tooltipInfo += row.this_year_label + ': ' + row.this_year + '<br>';
    }

    $jQueryObject.find('.morris-hover-row-label').html(tooltipInfo);
    $jQueryObject.find('.morris-hover-point').remove();
    return $jQueryObject.contents();
}

function differenceYear (year) {
    var previous_year_date = new Date(year,1,1);
    var previous_year = previous_year_date.getFullYear();
    var this_year_date =  new Date();
    var this_year = this_year_date.getFullYear();
    difference = this_year - previous_year;
    return difference;
}

function generateChartLegend(data_colors, data_labels){
    data_colors_rev = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data_colors));
    data_colors_rev = data_colors_rev.reverse();
    for(let elem  in data_labels){
        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        var label_div = document.createElement('div');
        var color_box_div = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.style.float = 'left';
        wrapper.style.margin = '0px 0px 0px 15px';
        label_div.innerHTML = data_labels[elem];
        label_div.style.display = 'inline';
        color_box_div.style.background = data_colors_rev[elem];
        color_box_div.style.float = 'left';
        color_box_div.style.width = '10px';
        color_box_div.style.height = '10px';
        color_box_div.style.margin = '4px 10px 0px 0px';
        wrapper.append(color_box_div);
        wrapper.append(label_div);
        $('#total_inspections_graph_legend').append(wrapper);
    }
}
generateChartLegend(data_colors, data_labels);
```

---

> Lines with style

```
<style>
#total_inspections_comparison_content_chart {
    min-width: 500px !important;
}
.total_inspections-scrollbar {
    max-height: 500px !important;
}
```

First graph:

[image]

Second graph is null because the first one is taking the result also from second:

[image]

Images

This is the new code that is used to add a new wiget to the page

```
private function generateWidgetContent($client, $instance)
{
    $instance = $this->widget_instance;
    $this->setContainerClass('col-lg-8 widget-box');
    $widget_interval = $this->widget_interval;

    $widget_parms = $this->widget_params;
    if(empty($widget_parms)){
        $widget_parms = 'this_month';
    }
    $title = ($widget_interval == 'per_month' ? 'Per Month' : 'Per Week');
    $sql_interval = ($widget_interval == 'per_month' ? '%Y%m' : '%Y%u');

    $title_parms = $this->getOptionTitle($widget_parms);
    $client = \SetInspect\ClassHelpers\CurrentClient::getClient();
    if(!$client instanceof \SetInspect\Eloquent\Models\Client){
        $this->setWidgetTitle($instance->widget->title .  ' (' . $title_parms . ' ' . $title .')');
        return NULL;
    }
    $date_range = $this->getRangeFromParam();
    $this->setWidgetTitle($instance->widget->title .  ' (' . $title_parms . ' ' . $title .')');
    $start_date_three_years_back = $this->sameDayLastYear($date_range->start_date, 3);
    $query_this_year = \SetInspect\Eloquent\Models\Appointment::with('appointmentSelectedPricingAttributes')->isBooked()->betweenDateTimes($date_range->start_date, $date_range->end_date);

    $previous_appointments = \SetInspect\Eloquent\Models\Appointment::with('appointmentSelectedPricingAttributes')->isBooked()->betweenDateTimes($start_date_three_years_back->format('Y-m-d'), $date_range->start_date);
    if(!ADMIN_SITE)
    {
        $query_this_year->byClient($client->client_id);
        $previous_appointments->byClient($client->client_id);
    }
    $appointments_this_year = $query_this_year->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(appointment_datetime, '".$sql_interval."') as appt_date, count(*) as cnt")
        ->groupBy("appt_date")
        ->get();
    $appointments_per_period_this_year = $this->summarizeData($appointments_this_year);

    $previous_appointments = $previous_appointments->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(appointment_datetime, '".$sql_interval."') as appt_date, count(*) as cnt")
        ->groupBy("appt_date")
        ->get();
    $appointments_per_period = $this->summarizeData($previous_appointments);

    $main_colors = [];
    $main_colors[] = '#71b6f9';
    $main_colors[] = 'red';
    $main_colors[] = 'orange';
    $main_colors[] = 'purple';

    $main_labels = [];
    $main_labels[] = gmdate('Y', strtotime('-3 YEARS'));
    $main_labels[] = gmdate('Y', strtotime('-2 YEARS'));
    $main_labels[] = gmdate('Y', strtotime('LAST YEAR'));
    $main_labels[] = intval(gmdate('Y'));
    $chart_data = array();
    $now = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    foreach($appointments_per_period_this_year as $year_date => $this_year_inspections)
    {
        $y = substr($year_date, 0, 4);
        $i = substr($year_date, 4, 2);
        $data = new stdClass();
        $dto = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        if($widget_interval == 'per_month') {
            $dto->setDate($y, $i, '1');
            $display = $dto->format('M Y');
        } else
        {
            $dto->setISODate($y, $i);
            $display = $dto->format('M d, Y');
        }
        $inspections_per_period = $this->inspectionsPerPeriod($appointments_per_period, $year_date);
        $data->period = $display;

        $data->this_year =  $this_year_inspections;
        $data->last_year = $inspections_per_period[$y - 1];
        $data->two_years_back =  $inspections_per_period[$y - 2];
        $data->three_years_back = $inspections_per_period[$y - 3];
        if($y == $now->format('Y')){
            $data->three_years_back =  $inspections_per_period[$y - 3];
        } else {
            $data->three_years_back =  0;
        }
        $data->this_year_label =  $y;
        $data->last_year_label =  $y - 1;
        $data->two_years_back_label =  $y - 2;
        $data->three_years_back_label =  $y - 3;
        $chart_data[] = $data;
    }

    if(empty($chart_data))
    {
        $this->setNoDataContent();
    }
    else
    {
        $view_data = [];
        $view_data['chart_data'] = $chart_data;
        $view_data['data_colors'] = $main_colors;
        $view_data['data_labels'] = $main_labels;
        $view_data['widget_parms'] = $widget_parms;
        $content = $this->load->view('widgets/total_inspections_comparison_content', $view_data, true);
    }
    if(!isset($content)){
        $content = 'No Data Available';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: FYI `data_colors_rev = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data_colors));` is nonsense, you just end up back where you started (because stringify is the reverse of parse). You can write `data_colors_rev = data_colors` and get the exact same result.

Comment: `second graph`...where is the code to create a second graph? You only call `createBarChart` once as far as I can see.

Comment: But anyway, you said you added two with the same name...well then how do you expect JS to tell them apart? Clearly they need to have different names.

Comment: @ADyson i added same graph twice in the same page and this happen, when there is only a graph this error dont appear, but when you add a second one this happen

Comment: Yes i know, you already said that. Again, why do you expect it to be ok when they both have the same name? Rename one of them and try again.

Comment: @ADyson well i dont think that will work i maybe need to generate an id or something like that when another graph is created, because the second one event a third one if is created will generate same data only they can change in base of month year or day

Comment: I don't really see what you're saying to be honest. I don't think your question contains a [mre] of your issue...that would help a lot.

Comment: @ADyson does it help if i send the file where the graph is add with php file, because the graph is added with php file in page

Comment: It might do yes. Like I said, you need to construct a [mre] of the issue for us.

Comment: @ADyson i added the code that is used to add widget, if you have time to check

Comment: You'd also need to show us how you're actually using that to generate multiple charts. I guess maybe that's in the view code somewhere? Again, we need a [mre] of the issue. All we have here is 3 separate, barely-connected bits of code. We could not use this to run the code or even walk through it to see the overall process and predict the output.